# AJAX success callback - issues executing javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-app-engine

When using AJAX to trigger a python handler (in GAE) upon load, it correctly loads the HTML template page, but for some reason it does not execute the Javascript that is in the template page. It also does not return that javascript in the success callback function.

This is the code from the index.html file that is triggering the handler upon load:

```
<div id="daily_emails"></div>

<script>
  $.ajax({
     url: "/gviz",
     cache: false,
     success: function(data){
       $("#daily_emails").html(data);
     }
  }); 
</script>
```

The gviz handler generates a html template that has a custom Google Chart Tools table in it. It creates it without any problem on its own, but once I call it from another html file (like above), it strips the javascript content and as a result returns the plain, unaltered, html. As the javascript code itself uses template tags (for the data in the Google Chart Tool), I can't just run it from the above index.html file.

If it would help, I could post the full code of the template that is being rendered by the gviz handler.

Comment: 1) What happens when you insert the response like so: `$("#daily_emails").text(data)`? This should avoid html enteties being created. 
2) Just to be safe, perhaps add an error callback, too and see if that gets called at some point or other?

Comment: Do you have handlers in your GAE for both post and get requests?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure your calls are made when the page is ready

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
     url: "/gviz",
     cache: false,
     success: function(data){
       $("#daily_emails").html(data);
     }
  });
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry, I must have misunderstood your question.

Comment: Wrapping it in a ready() function didn't help. The main issue is that when the template is rendered, the javascript within it doesn't execute, and as a result, when the html from the template is passed back through the use of the success callback function, the html from the template remains unaltered.

Answer (score 0):

Which browser are you using?  Browsers will parse the returned HTML, and may strip out illegal HTML.   This might happen if there's an error in the returned HTML.  It'll be helpful if you include the results of '/gviz'.

Since it sounds like you're returning a template that may not contain purely valid HTML, you may need to return the results with the content-type set to 'text/plain' so the browser doesn't attempt to parse it.